# Is it possible to set f(x) to user input in TI-Basic?

Tags: texas-instruments, ti-basic

I need to be able to set `f(x)` to user input in my program. For example the user inputs `x^3-3`. Then later in the program, a transformation can be applied to the function by using something like `f(2x)`. The output of `f(2x)` would be `8*x^3-3`. I am having trouble doing this though. I get user input with something such as `Input "Enter a function:", fx` and apply this value to the function with `Define f(x) = fx`. Now I will illustrate the problem with this. If a user inputs something such as `x^2-2`, if I call `f(2x)` it just returns `x^2-2` as if I called `f(x)`. I have tried many things such as `Define f(x) = expr(fx)`, `Define f(x) = eval(fx)`, and even pre-defining `f(x)` as `x`, and using `f(x)->f(fx)`, but none of these things worked. Is there a function that makes this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I realized that Ti-basic doesn't support function composition. There isn't really a way around it.